# get custom post type categories

Tags: custom-post-types, categories

From http://codex.wordpress.com:

```
$categories = get_categories( $args );

$args = array(
'type'                     => 'post',
'child_of'                 => 0,
'parent'                   => '',
'orderby'                  => 'name',
'order'                    => 'ASC',
'hide_empty'               => 1,
'hierarchical'             => 1,
'exclude'                  => '',
'include'                  => '',
'number'                   => '',
'taxonomy'                 => 'category',
'pad_counts'               => false 
);
```

I thought that 'type' was the post type. But not. This is the type of category to retrieve. I've researched without success.

So, any idea of how to retrieve all categories assigned to all post of specific post type?

Comment: This can be interpreted different ways. Do you mean categories assigned to specific post? Or all categories assigned to all post of specific post type?

Comment: @Rarst - Second one. I've updated my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A brute force solution that works for any post-taxonomy relationship:

```
global $wpdb;

// set the target relationship here
$post_type = 'post';
$taxonomy = 'category';

$terms_ids = $wpdb->get_col( $wpdb->prepare( "
    SELECT
        tt.term_id
    FROM
        {$wpdb->term_relationships} tr,
        {$wpdb->term_taxonomy} tt,
        {$wpdb->posts} p
    WHERE 1=1
        AND tr.object_id = p.id
        AND p.post_type = '%s'
        AND p.post_status = 'publish'
        AND tr.term_taxonomy_id = tt.term_taxonomy_id
        AND tt.taxonomy ='%s'
    ", $post_type, $taxonomy ) );

// here you are
$terms = get_terms( $taxonomy, array(
    'include' => $terms_ids,
    'orderby' => 'name',
    'order' => 'ASC'
) );
```

Comment: Brute force solution, but works. Thanks!